# How does android maintain network connection

Tags: android, ppp

I want to know how Android maintain the ppp connection at low level (not application level.)

To be specific, when the ppp connection failed (no signal or whatever reason), how did android sense it and try to reconnect? Does it periodically test the connection? if so, what's the interval?

I explored system/netd along with NetworkManagementService.java, ConnectivityService.java and some other related objects. I still couldn't figure the reason out.

Please advise. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as though you want to know how network connection is maintained at operating system level (and are you sure you mean a 'ppp' connection?).

Android itself is based on Linux which is written in C. If you want to delve into the networking code then it's freely available although it might be worth while exploring the ppp protocol first as this may give you a 'higher level' of how a connection is maintained rather than examining raw code.

The java code will be high level and won't as your research discovered reveal much if anything about the lower level workings.

I'm not sure what protocols are used on mobile/gsm connections but I'm sure a poke around on the internet or Wikipedia will reveal things.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know how to use at commands to establish ppp connection on cell. PPP here is just an example, it could be wifi though. The real thing I wanna know here is how android sense the signal loss and start re-connecting. By looking at the codes I mentioned in the original post, it looks like android maintains all network connectivity based on events and I dont understand how losing signal could generate an event. Thanks